# Transaction timeout with TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: transactions, ejb, weblogic

I have a J2EE application (weblogic, oracle) that sends large data over internet. But it suffers of transaction timeout. So I refactored the application following way:

Timer has container managed transactions, but callback has NOT_SUPPORTED flag.

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "TransferTimer", name = "TransferTimer")
public class TransferTimer implements ITransferTimerLocal {

    @Timeout
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void timeoutCallback(final Timer timer) {
            vo = transferController.prepareTransfer();
            if (vo != null) {
                transferController.sendData(vo);
                transferController.finishTransfer(vo);
            }
..
```

New bean was introduced with bean managed transactions. The long running method does not deal with transactions and database at all:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(value= TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class TransferController implements TransferControllerLocal {


    public TransferVO prepareTransfer() {
        TransferVO vo = null;
        try {
            userTransaction.begin();
..

    // no transactions must be there - it may take too much time
    public void sendData(TransferVO vo)  {
        client.sendFile(vo.getOrder(), vo.getArchive());
    }
```

Though TransactionTimeout exception is thrown, when client.sendFile() successfuly finishes.

```
Caused by: weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 61 seconds
BEA1-263D00276AD109CA0CA4
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.wakeUp(ServerTransactionImpl.java:1788)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.processTimedOutTransactions(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:1676)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerImpl.wakeUp(TransactionManagerImpl.java:1988)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.wakeUp(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:1586)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.WLSTimer.timerExpired(WLSTimer.java:35)
```

I do not understand it. Why does it fail?

Comment: Anybody can help me? My question is how to avoid J2EE container creating transaction in timer.

Comment: Have you solved this issue ? Did it had the same problem with other TransactionAttributeType ? The default JTA transaction timeout in weblogic is 30 seconds, you could try to increase that using admin console.

Comment: This was the ugly workaround we used. Unfortunate side effect is that it is a global settings that affects other beans.